# Error in data.table group by: was not possible to find the function "."

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to group by using data.table functions. But I get an error and appears a message like this:

> was not possible to find the function "."

My code is like this:

```
cad.agrupado <- cad.2[ , .(d.fx_rfpc = first(d.fx_rfpc),
                           d.marc_pab = first(d.marc_pab),
                           d.cod_local_domic_fam = first(d.cod_local_domic_fam),
                           d.dat_atual_fam = first(d.dat_atual_fam),
                           d.dat_cadastramento_fam = first(d.dat_cadastramento_fam)),
                       by = d.cod_familiar_fam]
```

I had unnistalled and installed again data.table, but nothing changed.

Comment: Provide example data, so we can replicate the issue. `dput(head(mydata))`. Also, check the class of the data: `class(cad.2)`

Comment: if that returns anything other than `c("data.table", "data.frame")`, then you can (1) force it one-time using `cad.agrupado <- as.data.table(cad.2)[, .(d.fx_rfpc ...), by=...]`; (2) or change `cad.2` to a `data.table` using either `setDT(cad.2)` or `cad.2 <- as.data.table(cad.2)`, after which your `.` should work. Note that if this is in a package and not just on the console, then the package needs to have `.datatable.aware=TRUE` in one of the `R/*.R` files; see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html.